# uWSGI is not creating Unix socket at specified path

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I've worked with Nginx and uWSGI numerous times, but I've never seen socket not being created even when specified explicitly.

My **uWSGI config** (`/etc/uwsgi/sites/my_site.ini`) is quite simple:

```
[uwsgi]
project = my_site
base = /root

chdir = %(base)/%(project)
home = %(base)/Env/%(project)
module = %(project).wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

socket = /run/uwsgi/%(project).sock
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true
```

As visible, uWSGI must create socket with `644` permissions (although some suggest it should be `666`).

**Nginx server configuration** (`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`) is quite simple as well:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    location /static/ {
        root /root/my_site;
    }

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/my_site.sock;
    }
}
```

**uwgsi.service (startup script)** (`/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service` on CentOS):

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor service
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After making these configurations, I executed following commands:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart uwsgi
sudo systemctl restart nginx
sudo systemctl status uwsgi
sudo systemctl status nginx
```

Everything was fine according to commands above, but Nginx returned 502 bad gateway) error when visiting website.

Thus I checked `/var/log/nginx/error.log/`:

> 2018/08/25 19:33:10 [crit] 14920#0: *3 connect() to unix:/run/uwsgi/my_site.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xxx.xxx.xx, server: my_site.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: $

As you can see above, uWSGI doesn't create socket at `/run/uwsgi/` directory for some reason...

I'm sure that socket is not being created at `/run/uwsgi/`, since `ls /run/uwsgi/` returns nothing.

**Permissions**:

`sudo usermod -a -G root nginx;chmod 710 /root`

## Main problem:

uWSGI is not creating a unix socket at the specified path in the configuration above, what could be the problem?

Is there any possible cause?

Comment: Are you sure the socket is not being created? What does `ls /run/uwsgi` show?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, `/run/uwsgi` directory is empty, which is very confusing. Maybe uWSGI doesn't have sufficient permissions?

Comment: How are you telling uwsgi to use that ini file? Show the startup script.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Updated question, I assume you meant `uwsgi.service` script?

Comment: Almost certainly permissions. Whats the output of `ls -al /run/uwsgi` ? Which user is uwsgi running as?

Comment: @miknik `ls -al /run/uwsgi` doesn't return anything either, but I too think there has to be something wrong with permissions. This is how I defined them: `sudo usermod -a -G root nginx;chmod 710 /root`

Comment: It doesn't return **anything?** Does that directory exist? `ls -al` even when run on an empty directory should still return a line for the directory itself `.` and a line for the directory above `..` similar to this
`drwxr-xr-x 2 miknik miknik 4096 Aug 26 13:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 miknik miknik 4096 Aug 26 13:24 ..`

Comment: @miknik I actually fixed the problem right now... It was a very simple misconfiguration problem, virtual environment path that uWSGI had to access was not specified properly. Therefore uWSGI was deleting the unix socket since it didn't have any access to Python environment (it couldn't import `site` module). I only found this out once I precisely analyzed `sudo systemctl status uwsgi`. Thanks a lot for the help.